# SQL Server : only display results of stored procedure under certain conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm currently working on a stored procedure that creates a table with many columns with many conditions. One of the requirements of this proc is that when column A has a value of YES then Column B must have a value. I have no idea how to code this but I was leaning towards a case statement in the where clause along these lines

```
CASE WHEN Table.A = 'YES' then Table.B is not NULL end
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that I'm not looking to only display results with these conditions. I would still like to include results where column A has values other than 'YES'. The only time i don't want any results to display is when both columns fall under those specific conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform it to

```
Where  (Table.A = 'YES' and Table.B is not NULL)
   OR  Table.A <> 'YES'
```

May be you should add the full query to get it added in right way to the query

Comment: If I include this in the where clause will it only give me results where A = 'YES' and B is not NULL or will it only apply if A = 'YES'?

Comment: @GabriellCarter It will check for both the conditions to satisfy (ie) `A` should be `YES` and `B` should be `NOT NULL`

Comment: So by adding this it will exclude all results where both conditions don't apply correct? I would still like to include results where column A has values other than A. The only time i don't want results to display is under those specific conditions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant values other than YES

Comment: @GabriellCarter - Updated my answer. You can do that by adding `OR` operator

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need to include other logic in your process, which you can achieve by nesting `case` statements like the below.  If not, Prdp's answer will be sufficient for your needs.

```
where case when Table.A = 'YES'
      then case when Table.B is not null
                then 1
                else 0
                end
      else 0
      end = 1
```